# I want to set state of parent component from child component during onChangeText in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I want to setName of parent component's state from child component while onCHangeText but it gives me "TypeError: setName is not a function. (In 'setName(text)', 'setName' is undefined)" error

Here is my Parent Component

```html
const ProfileCreationScreen = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState()
 


  const userSignup = async () => {
    try {
  
      firestore().collection('users').doc("androiduser_mobile89").set({
        name: name,
      });
      alert("Succesfully Created")
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  };


  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Create your account</Text>
      <Button
        mode="contained"
        onPress={() => userSignup()}>
        Sign Up
      </Button>
      <View style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <NameScreen setName={setName} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Here is my child component

```
export const NameScreen = ({ setName, navigation }) => {
return (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    enabled
    behavior="padding"
    style={styles.container}>
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Full Name</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textField}
        label="Enter your Full Name"
        underlineColor="#FF0074"
        outlineColor="red"
        value={text}
        onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
      />
      <Button mode="contained" style={styles.btn} onPress={() => alert(text)}>
        Next
      </Button>
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
```

Comment: The view is display none. How are u activating it. Also, troly console logging the function to see what will appear

Comment: I have two different screen/files and after typing name in child component we can go to next(parent) screen which have actual state which i want to send to firebase as name. I have similar other child components so I'm doing in this way.

Comment: And have you tried logging the function?

Comment: onChangeText={(text) => {setName(text); console.log("func",setName)}} i trued this and it gave TypeError: setName is not a function

Comment: Remove the event handler and add the logger before the return

Comment: It is showing undefined when i console it as <TextInput
            style={styles.textField}
            label="Enter your Full Name"
            underlineColor="#FF0074"
            outlineColor="red"
            value={text}
            onChangeText={text => 
            console.log(setName)}
            
          />